# Optaplanner - does processor impacts the compute time

Tags: cpu, optaplanner, hardware-acceleration, timefold

We are using Optaplanner in a project for 4-5 years now. As the business requirements grow we added a more and more rules. But now we are at a point where it takes around 10 days to generate an acceptable result on our server. We have already tried to optimize the rules, the source code, etc. with little positive impact. That means we decided to try running the projet and generate a planning with another computer (on the cloud), we picked a VM with significative better hardware (CPU wise). We measured that a lot more solution are processed per seconds (which is good), yet, the best scores does not seem to really outperform over time compared to our server... So in the end, we are kind of wondering if the CPU (when using decent ones) really matter? If so, what specifications should we looking for when picking a CPU to run an Optaplanner Solver ?

Note, we are at V8.x of optaplanner, we plan to migrate to v9.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPU power makes massive impact on the performance of OptaPlanner (or [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork/)), as the workload is entirely CPU-bound. To be successful, you need to look at as much of the search space as possible, and with a more powerful CPU, you'll get the same amount of work done more quickly.

(If you're purely after CPU power, you may be interested in hearing that Timefold is significantly faster than OptaPlanner by default.)

However, CPU performance is not the full picture. If your solution contains score traps, for example, the solver will never find better solution, no matter how hard it tries, or for how long. If you believe you hit the point of diminishing returns on CPU power, start looking for problems in your constraints.

Is there enough moves, and is there enough move diversity, to allow the solver to escape from local optima? Are there score traps in your constraints? I can not answer those questions for you. But they would be the questions I'd invest into finding the answers to.

In fact, we have an entire chapter in our documentation to deal with the issue of [getting better results out of the solver](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/score-calculation/score-calculation.html#scoreCalculationPerformanceTricks).

Comment: Thanks Lukas. I was not aware of Timefold, so we might look into it. We will also take another round of inspection for moves and score traps. 

When you say "CPU power" do you mean clock speed, number of cores (given the moveThreadCount is aligned properly), both, or something else ?

Comment: The multi-threaded solver currently has a soft limit at 4 move threads. Above that, it is unlikely to improve score speed; above 8, it is likely to even make it worse. If you want to be sure, benchmark it. Both multi-threaded solving and higher clock speed will lead to improvements, until you reach a point where they don't anymore.

Comment: Thanks. We also noticed that during the CH phase, the server with a better CPU provided a significative better solution after 12 minutes (limited at 20min) vs the other one that stops at 20min with a lower score. Do you think there is a point to increase the duration of  the CH phase when it does not terminate before the limited termination time ?

Comment: I am confused. CH is a deterministic algorithm. Every time it runs, it is guaranteed to give the same result. (Only perhaps faster on faster CPUs.) It is not possible to get a better final result on CH just because it is run on another CPU. If you see such behavior, I'd argue you should look for score corruptions in your constraints.